# How to uninstall Hadoop 1.0.0

Tags: hadoop

I set up my Hadoop clusters with Hadoop 2.0.2. Then, today I tried to test 1.0.0. So I downloaded the deb file from the Hadoop website and installed it: It did mess up everything.

Now, when I type "which -a hadoop" I get 2 results

- one pointing to my old Hadoop installation folder
- and the other one pointing to /usr/bin/hadoop.

So the question is: how to get rid off of Hadoop 1.0.0 completely?

Comment: IMO using packaging/installers for java stuff is almost always a mistake; the normal downloads give you complete control.

Comment: yeap, but that wasn't the answer to my question was it?

Comment: Nope, which is why it's a comment, and not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `dpkg -r hadoop`; this should remove the Hadoop package from the system, but leave the config files intact. If you want to lose the config files as well, try `dpkg -P hadoop` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
> $HADOOP_HOME
> /home/shiv/hadoop
> sudo rm -r /home/shiv/hadoop
```

And Hadoop is uninstalled!

Comment: Found extremely useful

Answer (score -1):

I struggled through this for longer than a while and then decided to share it here:

The trick is to basically delete all the symlinks pointing back to locations where HDP components reside since that is what causes 80% of the problem. Here is a step by step tutorial for that:

http://www.yourtechchick.com/hadoop/how-to-completely-remove-and-uninstall-hdp-components-hadoop-uninstall-on-linux-system/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your page link is broken